# How can I add custom field validation for one of the fields "within" an addressfield?

Tags: forms

I'm attempting to implement one of the answers to [this question on validating whether there no double-byte characters present](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33411/address-field-validation-how-to-allow-only-english-single-byte-characters).

Here is what I've done so far in my custom module:

```
function CUSTOMMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'profile_gen_node_form') {
    $form['#validate'] = 'CUSTOMMODULE_location_doublebyte_validation_handler';
  }
}
```

And then:

```
function CUSTOMMODULE_location_doublebyte_validation_handler($form, $form_state) {
```

This is where I'm stuck.  Addressfields include much more information than normal fields; they seem to be like a collection of fields.  Here is a screenshot of the output of `dpm($form)`:

[image: locality_block output]

I want to check `strlen()` and `drupal_strlen()` of the value of the "locality" piece of my addressfield but I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried something like this:

```
if(strlen("field_gen_loc_current['und']['0']['locality_block']['locality']") !== '0') {
    form_set_error('locality', t('No double-byte input.'));
}
}
```

But, while this doesn't produce an error, it also never causes the validation to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just chucked a validation function into a dev site with an addressfield and you're right, it's a bit strange. It might be that the address field is marked as `#tree => TRUE`, and that's what's causing the long element key string.

Either way, it looks like you're checking the `$form` variable in your validate function, when the submitted data will actually be inside `$form_state['values']`. A couple of other minor alterations and you should be able to get it working:

```
function validation_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Let's at least TRY to keep lines to 80 chars...
  $key = 'commerce_customer_profile|billing|commerce_customer_address|und|0';

  // Get the length of the 
  $length = strlen($form_state['values']['addressfield'][$key]['locality']);

  if ($length != 0) {
    form_set_error('addressfield', t('No double-byte input.'));
  }
}
```

That example is based on the Commerce add customer form, so you'll need to inspect the `$form_state['values']` array in your own form to find out exactly what the `$key` variable should be but hopefully that'll give you somewhere to start.

Just a note on your use of `!==` above...be careful with that, it will force PHP to make sure the *types* of the variables are equal, as well as the value.

`strlen()` returns an integer, and `'0'` is a string, so `strlen('string') !== '0'` will always return `TRUE`, regardless of whether the values are the same.

Comment: I'm having trouble determining the value for $key.  When I insert a `$print_r($form_state['values']['field_gen_loc_current'])`, I get the following: `Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [element_key] => node|profile_gen|field_gen_loc_current|und|0 [locality] => adsklfjaだからF [administrative_area] => HK [country] => JP ) ) )`.  When I tried using `node|profile_gen|field_gen_loc_current|und|0` as the value for $key, the returned strlen was 0, but the actual value for locality is `adsklfjaだからF`, so something is wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but did you change the `['addressfield']` part to the name of your field?

Comment: Yes.  When I do `$print_r($form_state['values']['field_gen_loc_current'])`, some information is output (as shown in the above comment).  However, when I add the [$key]['locality'] part, I don't get anything.

Comment: I solved it by modifying the array like this:   `$length1 = strlen($form_state['values']['field_gen_loc_current']['und']['0']['locality']);`

Comment: That actually would have made a lot more sense but it didn't work on the form I tried it on for some reason. Sorry if I led you down the wrong path

Comment: No, it was your comment that pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!